# how to set first page pagination link to active by default

Tags: php

This code only shows one of the pagination links as active if I click on it first. But on page load I want number "1" to be active by default.

```
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {

        $page = $_GET['page'];

    } else {

        $page = 1;
    }


for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
    if ($_GET['page'] == $page) {
        echo "<li class='pagination__page--active'><span>{$page}</span></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<li><a href='product-category/$page_url/page/{$page}'>{$page}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your problem, that only on page 1 it doesn't show the correct one as active?

If so, your problem is that you are probably not sending a 'page' with your GET request. The easiest way to solve this is:

```
$curr_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
    if ($curr_page == $page) {
        echo "<li class='pagination__page--active'><span>{$page}</span></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<li><a href='product-category/$page_url/page/{$page}'>{$page}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, if I go to page 2, the 2 shows as active. If I then click on 1 and go back t to page 1, then 1 shows as active but only because 1 is now in my url string. But on initial category page load when there is no page number in the url, nothing is set as active but I want 1 to show as active and not clickable.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said and solved with my answer? Okay, I wasn't specific enough with the on page 1 part, but it should work nonetheless, right?

Comment: Sadly, no. It doesn't work. Isn't this because even though you are setting the default of $page to 1, 1 still doesn't exist in the url?

Comment: I am assuming that the url looks something like this: www.example.com/content?page=1 or www.example.com/content and only the second one doesn't work? Because if so, this code should actually work. Would you mind sharing what curr_page is for both examples? (Just add `die($curr_page);` in front of the if)

Comment: url looks like: `mysite.com/product-category/shirts/` on initial load and after clicking a pagination link: `mysite.com/product-category/shirts/page/2`. The first link does not have "1" active as I would like it

Comment: I don't really understand where you want me to put the die($curr_page). Could you update the code in your answer, please?

Comment: Well, it is essentially the same. Just put the die directly after creating the `$curr_page` variable please. I don't want to update the code, as die() stops the further execution and outputs the given value (in this case `$curr_page`) and is in this case only used for debugging purposes.

Comment: I did what you asked and all that happens is that my pagination completely disappears. There is no error message from php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155166/discussion-between-sourceoverflow-and-user8463989).

Comment: Short explanation on why it didn't work: $_GET['page'] does not return an integer (which $page is). Therefore === did return false, but == is correct and should be working